# Request.get Download image before Image fully loads

Tags: python, image, python-requests

I am trying to download images from the website. `Request.Get` sometimes didn't download data, My assumption is when the images are heavy, `Request.get(url)` fails because the image takes some time to upload.

Failed

```
Remote URL https://gd3.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/917765107/O1CN01FUj4ea1nb3SEtYlCB_!!917765107.jpg
filename 1657077308/693904.jpg size  0
```

Success

```
Remote URL https://gd1.alicdn.com/imgextra/i1/917765107/O1CN016sR7UO1nb3SNr1Fo2_!!917765107.jpg
filename 1657077186/735590.jpg size  14032
```

Code:

```
# Getting image from remote url
response = requests.get(remote_url, stream=True)
# Get the content of image
imageResponse = response.raw
len(response.content)
```

Also check this , Image downloaded but Blank

```
remote_url = "https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/917765107/O1CN01WwxHa81nb3SLAupPq_!!917765107.jpg"
imageResponse = requests.get(remote_url, stream=True)
print(len(imageResponse.content))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `requests.Session`, it can fix the problem. If does not, then you have probably been blocked from `gd3.alicdn.com` host cause of making many requests.

```
import requests

urls = [
    "https://gd3.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/917765107/O1CN01FUj4ea1nb3SEtYlCB_!!917765107.jpg",
    "https://gd1.alicdn.com/imgextra/i1/917765107/O1CN016sR7UO1nb3SNr1Fo2_!!917765107.jpg",
    "https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/917765107/O1CN01WwxHa81nb3SLAupPq_!!917765107.jpg"
]

for url in urls:
    with requests.Session() as session:
        response = session.get(url, stream=True)
        print(len(response.content))
```